# Reviewed Action >> [Reviewed] ? what are the taken actions?

Tags: support, review

[Reviews Example](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1411844/tkanzakic?tab=activity&sort=reviews)

***note***: *I am not judging the guy - simply using it as an example*

[image: Reviewed]

Please, can someone tell me what did the guy physically do or change about the questions to get the `reviewed` status?
In other words: how to trace what he has done to achieve the `Reviewed` status?

Did he vote? revised? comment? what actions did he take?

Normally, there is a `no action needed` or something similar which is quite obvious what actions he took but in case it says `reviewed` what did he exactly do?

Comment: As long as voting is anonymous, it won't be shown.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd but there have been no votes on that question yet.

Comment: See my answer for more possibilities. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most actions can be seen on the post itself. For example for [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/2433491) if you go to [the question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17444873/447356) you can see it has a close vote, most likely cast by the reviewer.

Same go for comments and if you see downvote or upvote.

What we can't see are flags, except for flagging as duplicate which will cause automatic comment.

Comment: I am sorry, but where do you see that it has a close vote?

Comment: You can't view them on questions you don't own until you have 3k @mehow.

Comment: there we go thats why i cant see it. thanks. for me ( under 3k) it seemed like he has not taken any actions and got the `reviewed` status, but now I understand there are some unlocked features before you reach some reputation that leave you hanging about wondering where do things come from ;)

Comment: @mehow true, and keep in mind that even Jon Skeet can't see certain things like flags so we just have to trust the system. :)

Comment: @Wooble unless I'm utterly wrong, clicking that give different view. See for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/2432506), it's clearly saying *tkanzakic reviewed this 4 hours ago: **No Action Needed***

Comment: No, you're utterly right. Comment deleted.